# How to extract a word from a string in python

Tags: python, string, ethereum, web3py

Im getting functions from a smart contract in this format
I print them out in a loop:

```
allFunctions = contract.all_functions()
for text in allFunctions:
      print(text)

<Function approve(address,uint256)>
<Function balanceOf(address)>
<Function burn(uint256)>
<Function burnFrom(address,uint256)>
<Function decimals()>
<Function decreaseAllowance(address,uint256)>
<Function increaseAllowance(address,uint256)>
<Function mint(address,uint256)>
<Function name()>
<Function owner()>
<Function pause()>
<Function paused()>
<Function renounceOwnership()>
<Function symbol()>
```

Now I want to dynamically remove everything from this string so Im only left with the actual function name
which is approve balanceOf,name, owner pause etc...

I need to do this manually since a lot of smart contracts have different function names

So I can not use strip("<function ()>")
Any ideas on how I can solve this?

The ouptut type I get is

```
<class 'web3._utils.datatypes.allowance'>
```

Comment: what happens when you `print(type(text))` ?

Comment: <class 'web3._utils.datatypes.allowance'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all data in a string, you can use regex:

```
import re

a = '''<Function approve(address,uint256)>
<Function balanceOf(address)>
<Function burn(uint256)>
<Function burnFrom(address,uint256)>
<Function decimals()>
<Function decreaseAllowance(address,uint256)>
<Function increaseAllowance(address,uint256)>
<Function mint(address,uint256)>
<Function name()>
<Function owner()>
<Function pause()>
<Function paused()>
<Function renounceOwnership()>
<Function symbol()>'''

re.findall("Function (.*)\(.*\)", a)
```

## edit:

```
import re

allFunctions = contract.all_functions()
for text in allFunctions:
      print(re.findall("Function (.*)\(.*\)", text.__str__())[0])
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: @JoeBlow Edit yout question with the exact input and the output you want processed. As it is, what you posted is not valid python code, so it is difficult to help.

Comment: I have posted the python code, I just loop over allFunctions and below is what I get after from print

Comment: @JoeBlow try the edit?

Comment: doesnt work either
   return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @JoeBlow now try with the extra parentheses?

Comment: its better but I get this ['allowance']
['approve']
['balanceOf']
['burn']
['burnFrom']
['decimals']
['decreaseAllowance']
['increaseAllowance']
['mint']
['name']
I need a string

Comment: @JoeBlow you can get the first entry of the list that the regex outputs. See the edit

Comment: thanks this did work actually

Comment: What `contract` in the code (not defined)?

Comment: @YasserKhalil ask the person that asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Split using space, take the second element, split using parenthesis and take the first element

```
text = "<Function approve(address,uint256)>"
print(text.split(" ")[1].split("(")[0])


approve
```

Comment: I cant do this in a loop, it keeps saying text has no attribute split

Answer (score 0):

You can use split:

```
txt = "<Function balanceOf(address)>"

txt.split()[1].split('(')[0]
```

Comment: that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work:

```
functions = [func[:-1] for func in "".join(allFunctions).split('<Function ')][1:]
```